# Ajax call doesn't return success

Tags: c#, jquery, json, ajax

I have an Ajax call which returns an JSON object, within the object is a property that states if the call was a success or not. For some reason, even if the call comes back as a success, the AJAX never hits it, in-fact it always returns as a failure. Not sure why.

AJAX:

```
    function GetSubTaskStories() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Story.aspx/GetSubTaskStories",
            data: JSON.stringify({ id: GetSubTaskID() }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.success) {
                    alert("Success: True");
                } else {
                    alert("Success: False");
                }
            },
            error: function (data) {
            }
        });
    }
```

SERVER:

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string GetSubTaskStories(string id)
    {

        // Do some stuff.
        JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        try
        {
            var storiesObj = new { success = true, stories = stories };
            return jss.Serialize(storiesObj);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var error = new { success = false };
            return jss.Serialize(error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: when you say "it always returns as a failure", do you mean it runs the "success" function but then alerts "Success: False", Or do you mean it runs the "error" function? Incidentally, the signature of your error function is wrong, it should be Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown ) - see http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: What is fail message?

Comment: @ADyson, yes that's it. The object returns as a success but the "Success: False" hits instead of it returning a "True".

Comment: at the start of your success function, put `console.log(JSON.stringify(data));` and check that the structure of the JSON returned is definitely what you are expecting

Comment: @MichaelMao, the error message says "Success: False", even though the success property may be "true"

Comment: @ADyson, I've done that and it shows that the success is true:

**`"{"d":"{\"success\":true,\"stories\":[{\"id\":4,\"Title\":\"Create add/update screen\"},{\"id\":2,\"Title\":\"Add links\"},{\"id\":1,\"Title\":\"Fix mappings bug\"}]}"}"`**

Comment: try `data.d.success`

Comment: @phuzi still same problem.

Comment: Try adding this attribute to your `WebMethod`: `[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]` and on ajax-success you should log `data` to see what it really is.

Comment: Your code has no problem in my computer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're returning an object with a property `d` that is a string that contains the serialized version of your result. It's not easy to see from your example with all the quotes and escaped quotes.

Remove the `jss.serialize` and return the anonymous object as your result.

```
[WebMethod]
public static object GetSubTaskStories(string id)
{

    // Do some stuff.
    try
    {
        var storiesObj = new { success = true, stories = stories };
        return storiesObj;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var error = new { success = false };
        return error;
    }
}
```

Comment: This was indeed the problem!

I have changed my return to an anonymous object rather than serializing it and it worked fine!

Comment: I think according the comment this answer is right. But when I use jss.serialize I don't get the d

Comment: @MichaelMao I think this is an artefact of the string to JSON conversion that happens behind the scenes - a string on it's own is not valid JSON so the WebMethod/WCF wraps the string.

Comment: Also, on the success function, it must be:

**`if (data.d.success)`** and not **`if (data.success)`**

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, I think you need to change your success function to:

```
success: function (data) {
  if (data.d.success == true) {
   alert("Success: True");
  } else {
   alert("Success: False");
  }
}
```

in order to reflect the structure of the JSON being returned from the server

Comment: I tried this, but it still reports the same message: "Success: False"

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function GetSubTaskStories() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "GetSubTaskStories",
        data: JSON.stringify({ id: 5 }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            alert(Boolean(data.success));
            if (Boolean(data.success)) {
                alert("Success: True");
            } else {
                alert("Success: False");
            }
        },
        error: function (data) {
        }
    });
}
```

try use boolean function
[image]